# Is this simple proof of the triangle inequality correct?

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers, solution-verification, triangle-inequality

The triangle inequality states that for any complex numbers $z_1,z_2,\ldots,z_n$ we have
$$\lvert z_1+z_2+\cdots+z_n\rvert\leqslant\lvert z_1\rvert+\lvert z_2\rvert+\cdots+\lvert z_n\rvert.$$
When I first tried proving this result, I tried using induction and the proof was successful. In hindsight though, I'm wondering if there's a simpler way I could have proved it:

The triangle inequality is really stating that the shortest distance between two points is a straight line. Therefore, to prove this we may observe that
$$\begin{align}\lvert z_1+z_2+\cdots+z_n\rvert&=\lvert z_1\rvert\cos\theta_1+\lvert z_2\rvert\cos\theta_2+\cdots+\lvert z_n\rvert\cos\theta_n\\
&\leqslant\lvert z_1\rvert+\lvert z_2\rvert+\cdots+\lvert z_n\rvert\end{align}$$
as required, where $\theta_i$ is the difference between the argument of $z_i$ and the argument of $z_1+z_2+\cdots+z_n$.

Is this proof valid?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Note that your first equality is not correct (EG Think about what happen when $z_1 = -z_2$.) You could write it as an inequality, then the rest follows. (Or remove the absolute sign from $ \cos \theta_1$)

Comment: @CalvinLin Thank you for spotting that. Am I correct in saying that I should remove the absolute value signs from all the $\cos\theta_i$'s?

Comment: Yes. That's what I stated too.

Comment: @CalvinLin Thanks for your help. I have edited.

Comment: Then again, invoking the transcendental cosine function seems to be less simple than using $|x+iy|^2=x^2+y^2$ and induction. So valid: yes, simpler: no, in my opinion

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen If your issue is with "using cosine function which is transcendental", then we could reinterpret this approach via "hypotenuse of right triangle is the longest side, easily seen through Pythagorean theorem". This avoids the need for complex numbers, hence is simpler. (And of course, and could use the distance formula directly.)

Comment: From where did you get the first equality?

Comment: @md2perpe Resolving each complex number into components parallel (and perpendicular) to $z_1+z_2+\cdots+z_n$. Does that help?

Comment: Nice question. Following comments by Hagen von Eitzen and Calvin Lin: Let $s = z_1 + z_2 + \cdots + z_n.$ If $s = 0$ there is nothing to prove; so suppose that $s \ne 0.$ Write $w_i = z_i/s$ ($i = 1, 2, \ldots, n$). Then $w _1 + w_2 + \cdots w_n = 1.$ If we can prove that this condition on any $n$ complex numbers $w_1, w_2, \ldots, w_n$ implies $|w_1| + |w_2| + \cdots |w_n| \geqslant 1,$ the required inequality will follow. But the proof of the rewritten inequality is simple: $$ |w_1| + |w_2| + \cdots |w_n| \geqslant \Re{w_1} + \Re{w_2} + \cdots +\Re{w_n} = \Re(w_1 + w_2 + \cdots + w_n) = 1.$$

Comment: @A-LevelStudent. I think that step is a bit too big unless it has been proven before, for example in a lemma.

Comment: While this sounds all nice and good, what is your definition of the cosine function? If it's geometric, how would you show $|\cos(\theta)|\leq 1 \ (\forall \theta \in \mathbb R)$ without the triangle inequality? Can you do so without implicitly proving the triangle inequality somewhere between the lines? :P

Comment: @Steve I agree with you if we define it using basic right angled triangles, but if we use the unit circle definition of $\cos\theta$ then it is immediately clear that $\lvert\cos\theta\rvert \leqslant 1$, since $\cos\theta$ is simply the $x$ coordinate of a given point on the unit circle, which by definition lies between $-1$ and $1$, so I disagree with you then :)